# Freeing a malloc'd char* causing a segfault 11

Tags: c

I am a bit of a new newbie when it comes to C so this is probably a stupid question.

I have a structure array and one of the elements within the structure is a char *. I've calloc'd the memory as follows:

```
targetSummaryResult[row].target = calloc(1, sizeof(char *));
```

Row is equal to `1`.

Then a bit later on I want to free the memory again, I use the following code:

```
free(targetSummaryResult[row].target);
```

Row is still equal to 1 but I get a signal 11 segfault on the free and I cannot see why.

Comment: The reason is probably that the code between `calloc` and `free` overwrites the value of `targetSummaryResult[row].target` with some other value.

Comment: *"then a bit later on"* would sound like a hint to try freeing immediately afterward.  If you do, is is there a problem?  If not, how many lines need to run before the problem returns?  Then: which lines are those?  Also, if you're having memory problems, it can be helpful to go ahead and set up [Valgrind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valgrind)...it can catch certain kinds of errors as they happen.  It's especially important if you're doing a lot of manual and error-prone memory management--which you might also consider moving away from *(cough, tryC++, cough)*

Comment: "...and I cannot see why" Neither can I. I would suspect this is because there is no code to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things, first.

```
targetSummaryResult[row].target = calloc(1, sizeof(char *));
```

where did you check if that `calloc` was successful.

Next did you initialize the target pointer to something else, like for example:

```
targetSummaryResult[row].target = "apple";
```

Or did you free it already before calling this:

```
free(targetSummaryResult[row].target);
```

freeing a memory twice can cause segfaults.

EDIT:

If you meant to do something like this:

```
targetSummaryResult[row].target = calloc(1, sizeof(char *));
targetSummaryResult[row].target = "apple";
```

then you should do it something like this:

```
targetSummaryResult[row].target = calloc(strlen("apple")+1, sizeof(char));\\+1 for the NUL terminating character in valid strings
//check if calloc was successful and handle errors if any
strcpy(targetSummaryResult[row].target,"apple");
```

Comment: I did assign it a value like what you have got there on your second quote. If that is wrong how would I assign a value to target after it is calloc'd. Sorry if this is a dumb question I'm very new to C and learning it as I go

Comment: @Boardy: you should first allocate memory, then use `strcpy`  and initialize the memory. Let me know if you still got problems.

Comment: @Boardy Assigning to a pointer does **just that** -- it assigns to the pointer itself. It does not do any sort of copying (C is not C++, fortunately). Hence you overwrite the pointer and then try to `free()` something that was not returned by an allocator function. That results in undefined behavior, which, in this case, appears to be manifesting itself in a segfault.

Comment: sizeof(char) is defined to always be 1.

Comment: OK, I'm starting to think that maybe I shouldn't be using callog as I don't know how long the string is going to be as its from a database so its mixed length. Perhaps I should be using strdup or asprintf

Comment: @Jite If I just wrote `1` instead of `sizeof(char)` which one will be more readable and easily understood?

Comment: @Boardy: `strdup` is not ISO C, but rather POSIX-only function. Besides its `malloc/calloc + strcpy` or basically the 3 lines in my first EDIT in answer+ a return pointer statement, wrapped into one function. You still have to `free` the `strdup`ed memory.

Comment: @Boardy: `asprintf`  is a GNU extension and available only with `gcc`.  Besides, its similar(not same) to `strdup` and in both the functions, you have to check if the returned pointer is `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks for your help it was to do with me malloc'ing the memory and then doing myChar = "hello"; screwing up the pointer. I've sorted this now and my free seems to work OK

Comment: @askmish If one doesn't have the ability to understand the meaning of `1` in the context, one shouldn't use C or definitly go learn to do it properly. Sometimes things don't get easier by stupifying them.